# Java : In console Thai text is printing as some strange character

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding, thai

When I am printing thai character in console it is showing some strange character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        byte[] bytes = "ฝ่ายขาย".getBytes("TIS-620");
        String str =  new  String(bytes);
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

It is printing 
���¢��

Comment: is your console able to print non-ACSII characters?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara  How will I check that?

Comment: Why are you converting from a string to bytes and then back to a string? If the encoding is the same, the string will be the same and if not it will be garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using eclipse in Windows, to enable UTF-8 in console (given that your IDE is able to use UTF-8 encoding `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Test File Encoding = UTF-8` ):

1. Go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`, select the JRE and Edit. Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to Default VM arguments (alternatively you can edit your eclipse.ini and add this argument but it doesn't work for me)

[image]

2. Select a UTF-8 supporting console font: `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearence -> Debug -> Console Font` (select Arial, Calibri etc)

[image]

3. Remove "TIS-620" explicit encoding from your method as you need it in UTF-8 encoded form

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = "ฝ่ายขาย".getBytes();

        String str = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Which is, as pointed out in the comments, simple String print

```
System.out.println("ฝ่ายขาย");
```

**Output:**

> ฝ่ายขาย